# Setfacl not working correctly in dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I added setfacl command in my dockerfile put its not executed in the product image, however, when I executed manually inside the image container its working perfect
I tried using RUN command and its not working
i read before that ACL commands not preserved in the docker image so
these 3 lines are part of my Dockerfile which is Script containing the setfacl commands I want to execute

```
COPY script.sh .
RUN chmod +x script.sh
RUN sh script.sh
```

and the script contain

```
#!/bin/bash
setfacl -R -d -m g::rwx /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/ 
setfacl -R -d -m o::rw  /var/www/html/storage/framework/views/ 
mkdir create-testdir-to-make-sure-that-script-is-executed
```

the test dir executed successfully, whereas the setfacl didn't make any effect cause when i create any file in the container in the views dir its not take the permisions in the setfacl

Comment: Please help to share your dockerfile

Comment: `its not executed` How do you check that? `its not working` How do you know it's not working?

Comment: You don't say whether the test directory is created.